Strange system and program crashes on Windows 11
I recently decided to upgrade to Windows 11, since my PC meets the requirements. Just in case, I’ll give you a list of my devices:

NVIDIA RTX 3050
Intel Core i7-9700KF
MSI Z370

After the upgrade I encountered two problems that occur at a random moment:

Program crashes. In absolutely any program or game, the issue is related to memory reading (probably). I connected the debugger remotely to my Windows (WinDbg) and before the crash I see the following message:
WATCHDOG: hRim=354[P:address,T:address]dwInputType:1 delayed read
and then access violation occurs in any places. This did not happen in Windows 10 and I do not think that these problems are related to their game code.
When I open minidump, I see an access violation in a new place every time:
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID: SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT_AVRF_c0000005_steamclient64.dll!Unknown (then I play cs2)

The entire system freezes. Once again, when I’m in a game or a basic notepad, my entire computer may freeze (the screen stops updating) and soon it will stupidly reboot. There is nothing in WinDbg


I have already carried out all sorts of system checks via sfc /scannow and dism - everything is fine there. Everything works fine on old Windows 10. Kernel memory integrity checks is disabled in Windows Defender. I don’t use any tweakers, OldNewExplorer or other programs that can change system dlls.
UPD: All drivers are installed and updated

It may just be a bad windows install. Don't forget an upgrade from 10 to 11 or 22h1 to 22h2 all reinstall windows in one way or form, and sometimes something may bork during an install. You may be able to fix it with a reinstall of windows.

I downloaded windows from the official website. my current version is 23H2, all updates are worth it

Yes, but even then, an install is always unique because so much happens during it, and sometimes things just bork up. You can do 2 identical windows installs on the same computer, and it may happen that one of them is unstable while the other one is not. It does not happen often that an install goes unstable, but it does happen maybe once every 50 times.

Even if this is due to a bad installation, how can I catch this "freeze"? Even windbg doesn't help me

You reinstall windows

I reinstalled it again, this time through a program from Microsoft. the problem remains
